# save a named tuple in all rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, namedtuple

I'm trying to save a named tuple `n=NamedTuple(value1='x'=, value2='y')` in a row of a pandas dataframe.

The problem is that the named tuple is showing a length of 2 because it has 2 parameters in my case (value1 and value2), so it doesn't fit it into a single cell of the dataframe.

How can I achieve that the named tuple is written into every call of a row of a dataframe?

`df['columnd1']=n`

an example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd

n = namedtuple("test", ['param1', 'param2'])

n1 = n(param1='1', param2='2')

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
df['nt'] = n1

print(df)
```

Comment: You could create a small `Class` instead of the named tuple

Comment: I need a named tuple

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve here? `df['nt'] = n1` assigns `n1` to the entire column, is that what you want? i.e. you're trying get the same result as `pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "nt": [n1, n1, n1]})`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to put that named tuple in every row of a new column (i.e. like a scalar) then you can't rely on broadcasting but should instead replicate it yourself:

```
df['nt'] = [n1 for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Comment: in my above example I still get an error when `df['nt'] = [[n1]]`

Comment: does pandas convert the named tuple to a tuple? It seems to lose its name. Otherwise this solution is great.

Comment: I think it does @Nickpick